# How to get value of timeout on a sleeping thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I set timeout on threads for 1 hour.
At some point downstream I want to know the timeout in millisecond that I had set on the thread. Is there a way to know it ?

I cannot find a property that would return me the tmieout value set on a sleeping thread.

mythread.sleep(3600000)

if mythread.ThreadState = ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin Then

mythread.GetTimeoutValue() ?  // is there a way to get this value

endif

Comment: Ummm....save it in a read-only instance var/property, maybe set by some sleep() method?

Comment: I want to know if there is something on the thread class itself that can tell me how much timeout was set or is balance currently since it was set.

Comment: Well, since that is an unusual requirement, and easily implemented anyway if needed, (eg in. a subclass, as I suggested), why look deeper?